# Create an "Other Server" clustered role on failover cluster manager and add a generic service to it using powershell

Tags: powershell, failovercluster

I wish to create a clustered role of type "Other Server" as per the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/create-failover-cluster) after scrolling down to create clustered roles. While there are cmdlets to create other types of clustered roles, such as generic service with cmdlet Add-ClusterGenericServiceRole and others listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/add-clustergenericservicerole?view=windowsserver2022-ps), there doesn't seem to be a way to make one of type "Other Server".

I tried playing around with Add-ClusterGenericServiceRole which allowed me to create the role, add a static IP address, and connect a generic service to it in one line:

`Add-ClusterGenericServiceRole -Cluster "MyCluster" -StaticAddress "192.0.0.0" -ServiceName "ServiceName" -Name "RoleName"`

Any guidance on how to the same for a clustered role of type "Other Server"? Or even changing the type of the clustered role to "Other Server" but keeping the service underneath it as type "Generic Service"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Need to create a group from scratch with grouptype unknown as follows:

```
Add-ClusterGroup -Cluster "MyCluster"  -Name "RoleName" -GroupType Unknown
```

Then add IP Address, Network Name and Generic Service separately.